# Converting a Authenticated curl request to Apache Camel Request

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, camel-ftp

```
curl -s -S -u user123:321pass https://12.15.13.12:3216 --data 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data>Hello Man</data>' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -k
```

I need to change this to a Apache Camel route call like :-

```
private ProducerTemplate producer;// there are setters for this.
producer.requestBodyAndHeaders(endpointUri, requestBody,addHeaders, String.class);
```

Main question is **how do I pass username and password** with this requestBodyAndHeaders.I tried passing through headers(header being map, key value pairs)